# Node not installing in docker image but also not erroring?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

Below is my docker image and I'm trying to install a new version of node. The one available with `apt-get install` is version 12 which is too old for my requirements. I have tried a few ways I've found on SO and GH but this one seemed the most promising. It builds fine but when I run the container after building it `node` isn't found and I've looked around the container and can't find it. Any idea why this isn't working? When I run the install commands in the running container I end up with a working correct version of node.

```
FROM osrf/ros:iron-desktop

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN chmod +x /opt/ros/iron/setup.bash
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/opt/ros/iron/setup.bash "]

RUN echo "source  opt/ros/iron/setup.bash" > startup.bash

# Node installation
RUN apt-get update \
    apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg \
    mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg \
    NODE_MAJOR=20  \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list  \
    apt-get update \
    apt-get install nodejs -y

ENTRYPOINT [ "/ros_entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "bash" ]
```

Edit: Confirmed that `apt-get install`s aren't sticking around at all by trying to install `tree` as well.

Edit2:

ok.... No idea why this created an issue but removing these two lines let `apt-get install` packages install correctly. Must be something specific to the ROS setup scripts.

```
RUN chmod +x /opt/ros/iron/setup.bash
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/opt/ros/iron/setup.bash "]
```

Comment: Please do not use certain abbreviations like `SO` and `GH` in your questions, it's hard to understand.

Comment: This seems like you're trying to install Node on top of some other runtime environment, and the `SHELL` lines look unusual to me (you shouldn't usually need to change the `SHELL` at all, and the second one seems like it will ignore the text of `RUN` commands).  Can you just start your Dockerfile `FROM node:20`?

Comment: Yeah, I needed NodeJS running in a ROS2 docker image. I forgot why the SHELL command got up there, but it had to do with making sure the ROS env got set up correctly. It turns out the `chmod` and `SHELL` commands were totally useless _and_ prevented `apt-get install` from working somehow, so that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your "RUN" instruction is wrong. It's building a long line as one command:

```
apt-get update apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings ...
```

which fails, of course. There should be an error message during that "RUN".

Put `&&` before `\` to fix.

Comment: I thought that too but it doesn't error on build that way and node still isn't installed after building if I run them each in their own RUN instruction.